# Flutter - How to underline each character in a text field?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How does one underline for each character in Flutter? I want to do phone verification and want each line to hold a single character but don't know how to do it (or if it's even possible) with a single TextForm.

Example:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rephrased version of this question: [Connecting multiple text fields to act like a single field in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65019013/connecting-multiple-text-fields-to-act-like-a-single-field-in-flutter)

Flutter package that handles this: https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields

Answer (score 1):

Use this :

```
 TextField(
                          obscureText: true,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          maxLength: 1,
                        ),
```

Must Add this In your ThemeData:

```
ThemeData(
         primarySwatch: Colors.red,
         accentColor: Colors.amber,
```

For Your Case You Can Dow that

```
Row(
children<>[

     TextField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              maxLength: 1,
                            ),

     TextField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              maxLength: 1,
                            ),

     TextField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              maxLength: 1,
                            ),

     TextField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              maxLength: 1,
                            ),

     TextField(
                              obscureText: true,
                              keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              maxLength: 1,
                            ),
]
)
```

For Layout Fixing use `Exapand()`